# How does one install lilypond and denemo without all of latex base being auto installed Ubuntu linux

Tags: installing, ubuntu, linux, lilypond

I'm trying to install denemo on an Ubuntu Linux computer without hosing my entire texlive system.

Does anybody know how to accomplish it?  The Ubuntu version is always oldy old, it points the sytem to a different texlive, fails to understand a more recent version is installed etc.

Any help appreciated.

command was

> sudo apt-get install denemo

I have been getting away without hosing my system by installing lilypond in a stand alone directory, and copying a link to the binary wherever I want to compile. But I would like to be able to install lilypond and denemo itself in a normal way without hosing my texlive system.

Best I can tell install equivs. Then I use equivs-control to make something to compile against. Then I, one by one, compile each of the offending filenames into a dummy package, install as if they are real packages. Is that right? Is there a better way to do this then one by one compiling individual dummy packages? Any script?

[image]

[image: Apt-get output]

Comment: I would suggest a TeXlive standalone install. Easier to maintain, and you can tune it to have only the package you want, and you update them whenever you want. Disclaimer: I don't know if lilypond and denemo are packed in texlive.

Comment: The problem with that is even if its standalone the apt-get system will overwrite everything and start pointing to the "new installation" when one installs either lilypond or denemo.  I've a couple of times researched where my old/new texlive system resided, and corrected it to the correct one.  But lately haven't had enough time to re-research where the Ubuntu texlive resides, its kind of a whack a mole throughout the years. It did occur to me perhaps there might be a dpkg way of installing part of a deb package??

Comment: I remember that in ArchLinux, the workaround was to load a package named `texlive-dummy` (doesn't exist anymore) that makes the package manager believe texlive is already installed. I would try to make something like this for ubuntu.

Comment: We have an answer on this site providing details for installing vanilla TeX Live on Debian. What that says about dummy packages is true for Ubuntu as well.